# Why does IsClientScriptBlockRegistered always return false in debug mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the code behind, I have the following code:

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("Script1"))
   Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Script1", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('test');</script>");
```

This code seems to work fine, but when I try to debug it `Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("Script1")` always returns `false`.  I even opened the quick watch window and was able to find the script under `_clientScriptBlock`.

Any idea why this is?

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET Ajax?

Comment: Yes I do.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: Try to use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163354.aspx

Comment: I tried ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock, but since ScriptManager does not give you a function to check if the script is registered.  Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered does return true when not running in debug, but in debug mode it behaves the same.

Comment: Are you in an asynchronous postback? You can check it with `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack`. You don't need to register the script if it's  an async postback. On the other hand, may be that's the problem. You want to execute a script that is in the header. But on an async postback only part of the page gets rendered, not the header. So the script wouldn't execute anyway. If i remember correctly you have to use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript with the correct UpdatePanel as argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion... I actually need to register the script block on the async postback.  My code is functional, and was just wondering why when in debug it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `GetType()` method parameter to ensure you're isolating the correct script block, like this:

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(GetType(), "Script1"))
{
    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Script1", 
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('test');</script>");
}
```

Comment: Does anybody know if the 'IsClientScriptBlockRegistered' executes its check for the current page-cycle or for the current session?
Meaning: should I re-register the script after a postback?